# Reversing repository version to older version of Subversion

Tags: linux, apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I was using SVN repository for some time but now I'd like to move it to my hosting account as there appeared a possibility of creating own SVN repositories lately. This option seems to be better for me.

But it appears that version of SVN server on a hosting is older than my repository, because when I moved all the repository files, I got this error from TortoiseSVN:

```
SVN Error: Expected fs format '2'; found format '4'
```

So I tried:

- Changing db/format file from "4 layout sharded 1000" to "2"
- Changing db/current file from "60" to "60 nx 2"
- Moving revision files from db/revs/0/0 to db/revs/0
- Same with db/revprops/

Then everything seemed to work fine, I was able to commit new changes, to update, but when I tried to "Show log" in TSVN, I got an information that it couldn't connect to repository with an error:

```
Invalid change kind in rev file
```

I assume that's because of rev files which are also of different version that they should be.

So my question is, is there any possibility of getting this working again?

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you haven't tried the most obvious tool: [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnadmin). A combination of `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` should do the trick.

Additionally, [svnrdump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump) can also be handy.

Make sure you dump a version of the repository you haven't damaged ;-)

**Update:**

Since you were editing the repo files, I assumed you had full access. You need SSH access for that (that's unrelated to Cpanel). If your server runs 1.4 or newer, you can simply use `svnrdump`. Additionally, just ask the support guys what tools they offer to import a repo.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how can I use svnadmin if on hosting, in cpanel I (I think so) only have access to some basic svn management center in which I can add new groups, users, etc?